# What does this sentence mean?

Tags: translation, words

> ５千円からお預かりいたします。３千円のおつりでございます。

I don't understand the use of 預かる here. Jisho says it means "to look after" "to keep in custody" so I can understand a sentence like これを預かっていただけませんか and ここで手荷物を預かっていただけますか but not the first one above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ５千円からお預かりいたします。３千円のおつりでございます。

"Out of 5,000 yen (note). Here's your change, 3,000 yen."

---

According to 明鏡国語辞典...

> あずかる【預かる】
>   ➍《「○○円からー」の形で》〔俗〕売り手が釣り銭の必要な代金をいったん手元に引きとる。
>   「千円からお預かりします」▹近年、コンビニなどから出た言い方。「まずは○○円から、仮に預かる」という気持ちで言っていると思われる。

So... 「○○円から預かる」 seems to be a pretty new and slangy usage. (But 「○○円(を)預かる」 doesn't sound slangy, as discussed in the comments below.) The dictionary says it's probably used in the sense of "First, I'll keep (hold of) ¥○○ tentatively."

Comment: 「から」はともかくとして、「から」なしの「1万円お預かりします」も普通にあると思うんですが、それも俗な言い方の扱いなんでしょうか（今手元に明鏡がないので）

Comment: So in that situation the bill is 2000¥ and the customer gives 5000¥, that's the use of 預かる?

Comment: @naruto そうですね・・「から」なしなら、普通な感じしますよね。。

Comment: @user27223 Right, when the bill is 2,000 yen and the customer gives 5,000 yen, then the shop clerk will say "I'll 預かる 5,000 yen."